# Why google insist that I used 30GB of storage?

Tags: google-drive

My whole google drive, with files, consist of only 2.5 GB.

I have no idea what else I should throw away.

Yet google insist I am using 30GB of space.

I wonder if I can see detail where do I use those space

Google claim I uses 30GB more

But the screenshot clearly shows that I am using a mere 3.5 GB. I wonder what I actually used. The google photos is moved somewhere else too and that's at most a few gigabytes. Trash is empty

[image]

[image]

The duplicated question have no answer.

In fact, I upgraded my storage to 100GB. Guess what? Google still complain that I don't have enough room.

Comment: Your storage may include items not in your local Google drive, such as deleted items in `Bin` and back-ups from 'phones and other devices in `Backups`. Have you looked at these folders?

Comment: So did you check Google Photos and Google Mail yet? There may be an accounting error. Also, do you even have the entirety of your Google Drive synced to your PC?

Comment: phones and other devices in backups? Where can I see it?

Comment: I have my entire google drive synced to my PC. First time it hits 30GB is a long time ago. I removed some files and it still have problems. What back up folders?

Comment: In response to your edit, the duplicate definitely has an answer.  It's likely that you haven't emptied the trash as the answer states.

Comment: I did. Also after upgrading the google app to 100 GB I keep getting notification that my site is full,.

Answer (score 0):

> These items take up space:
>
> - Google Drive: Most files in your "My
>   Drive," including PDFs, images, videos. Items in your Trash. Learn how
>   to empty your trash. Note: Your storage isn't used by Google Docs,
>   Sheets, Slides, Forms, and Sites.
> - Gmail: Messages and attachments,
>   including items in your Spam and Trash folders.
> - Google Photos: Photos
>   and videos stored using the "Original" size. (You can change the size
>   so photos and videos don't use storage. Learn more about photo
>   storage.)

Source: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6374270?hl=en

Edit: Also the earlier versions of files (file change history) may take up that space.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I already reduce google drive and google photos

Comment: Maybe the earlier versions of files (file change history) take up that space, as the answer in the duplicate question suggests.